# Access Datalake from local python securely

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake

I would like to access the contents in my Azure Datalake gen 2 via my local python editor? What would be the best way to do this?

I googled, but there are multiple ways to do this - SAS, Service principle for instance.

Could someone please provide any pointers in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can use azure ad authorize.

Comment: Thank you, but some of the people, who would eventually access the datalake are not present in Azure AD yet. How should provide them access with?

Comment: Hi, any update? Have you test it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake.datalakeserviceclient?view=azure-python

And use this to create credential:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
```

And for any one you want it to access, you need to add access role([RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles), people without corresponding permissions cannot perform specific operations.):

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

You can try above steps.

Comment: Hello @Bowman - I was able to test it today. Thankyou. I was able to link the datalake and print out all the file paths within my container. However, how do I read the contents of the file within them? Any pointers is appreciated :)